# Создание профилей в vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть ли возможность в vscode использовать несколько разных профилей с настройками, чтобы в каждом профиле был свой набор установленных и включенных настроек и в каждом профиле были свои настройки расширения?

Допустим, в один из профилей мне нужно расширение для работы с гитхабом, а в другом кастомный плагин для TFS, в первом мне нужны плагины для работы с bootstrap, vue, в другом это не нужно.

Пробовал поискать во встроенной справке и погуглить -- не нашёл, что такое возможно из коробки. Или всё-таки возможно?

Comment: [workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) это не то же самое?

Comment: как вариант можете написать консольное приложение которое папку .vscode переименовывает в .vscode1, а .vscode2 в .vscode и наоборот

Comment: @Grundy Судя по описанию -- то, что нужно. Попробую на выходных, а вообще - вы б в ответы вписали.

Comment: @AK, на ответ не хватает :-) да и не пробовал сам, так, краем уха слышал только, поэтому и ссылка :-) как попробуешь - добавь ответ с подробным описанием

Comment: Как вариант можно поставить VSCode Insiders для второго профиля. Это самое простое решение :) Ну или как писали выше лепить скрипты. Вот пример такой настройки на Маке под zsh https://github.com/avanslaars/code-profiles Можно еще через дополнение Settings sync попробовать создать 2 разных gist и синхронить их по очереди. Не знаю как будет работать, не пробовал, но как вариант тоже можно рассмотреть.

Comment: @Grundy Дошли руки разобраться - оформил ответом.

Answer (score 6):

Итак, решение на базе workspace, которое посоветовал в комментариях @Grundy оказалось очень рабочим.

Ответ обкатывался на windows, возможно я позже повторю все те же действия на виртуалке с debian и добавлю в ответ версии хоткеев для nix-систем.

Итак, идём в документацию и [смотрим](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) введение в матчасть. Настройки хранятся в двух разных местах:

- глобальные настройки, которые применяются ко всем экземплярам vscode запущенными в любой папке. Хранятся в `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- настройки для workspace (конкретной открытой папке), применяется к экземплярам vscode, запущенным в этой конкретной папке. Хранятся в файле `.\vscode\settings.json`

Я тестировал это на простой настройке "The default end of line character.":

```
{
    "files.eol": "\n"
}
```

Проверяется легко и быстро: создал новый файл и смотришь в статусной строке, он имеет тип LF или CRLF.

Это была часть предварительная. Вторая часть - как включать и выключать расширения в зависимости от "профиля". Тут хорошо ознакомиться с [ещё одной ссылкой](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15611) - обсуждение на гитхабе фичи включения/выключения расширения через конфиг.

Видно, что предлагался интуитивно понятный вариант хранить в .vscode/settings.json
 что-то типа:

```
{
  "extensions.enabled": ["ms-vscode.csharp", ...enabled],
  "extensions.disabled": [/*whatever extensions wanted to be*/...disabled],
}
```

Но в итоге разработчики сделали чуть иначе: это не хранится в конфиг-файле .vscode/settings.json поэтому закинуть в папку файл настроек не получится :( но вполне можно накликать мышкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно будет сделать. Допустим, у нас есть расширение Vetur и мы решаем, что у нас в основном работа в vscode идёт с кодом на c# и иногда (читай - много реже) нам приходится открывать vue.js проекты. Тогда мы берём и глобально выключаем расширение Vetur, а потом заходим во все наши фронтенд-проекты и для них включаем расширение обратно, но уже локально, для конкретного воркспейса.

Все эти параметры хранятся - но не в папке .vscode, а в папке `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где путь к папке записан в файл workspace.json:

```
{
  "folder": "file:///c%3A/git/github.com/user/prog/frontend"
}
```

, а конкретные параметры workspace'а хранятся в файлах sqlite.

Так что копировать настройки с какого-другого workspace становится немного сложнее: основная сложность - найти папки, у меня лично уже полсотни worspaces'ов из-за того, что смотрю много проектов на гитхабе. Но в целом проблем никаких нет: я создал на диске папки test1 и test2 с разными настройками расширений, а потом просто закрыл vscode и скопировал файл state.vscdb из папки в папку - и настройки при очередном открытии были такие же, как и в другом workspace.

Так что если вдруг придётся держать очень разные настройки форматтеров/линтеров и тому подобных расширений, то в принципе можно просто скопировать настройки с другого проекта.

Comment: AK, привет подскажи такую штуку, а папка `.vscode с фалом launch.json` должна храниться к конкретной папку с проектом, если нет, то с чего вдруг она появилась...???  Я понимаю, что ты не ясновидящий...  Я пару дней как открыл для себя `gitHubGist`

Comment: @Air Сам нажал кнопку create/fix configuration :) [см. тут](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging). Да, лежит в папке проекта в .vscode.

Comment: AK, благодарю....